# Difference between IDE and Framework

Tags: frameworks, ide

What is a difference between an IDE and Framework with respect to Java?

Answer (score 31):

Basically :

- The IDE is the software you use to develop ; for example, Eclipse is an IDE *(code editor, debugger, build tools ... )*
- The Framework is a set of both libraries and best practices that help you not re-invent the wheel, and provide a set of guidelines on how to develop.

Quoting wikipedia, an [**IDE**](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) :

> is a software application that
>   provides comprehensive facilities to
>   computer programmers for software
>   development. An IDE normally consists
>   of:
>
> - a source code editor
> - a compiler and/or an interpreter
> - build automation tools
> - a debugger

While a [**Framework**](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Software_framework) :

> is an abstraction in which common code
>   providing generic functionality can be
>   selectively overridden or specialized
>   by user code, thus providing specific
>   functionality. Frameworks are a
>   special case of software libraries in
>   that they are reusable abstractions of
>   code wrapped in a well-defined
>   Application programming interface
>   (API), yet they contain some key
>   distinguishing features that separate
>   them from normal libraries.

Answer (score 13):

An IDE is an application used to write and compile code.  A framework is generally a software component that someone else wrote that you can use/integrate into your own project, generally to avoid re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 4):

A framework is a tool that is closely attached to the language you are using and usually extends upon or adds the the language features.

An IDE (Integrated Development Environment) provides automation support for the language you use with regards to syntax highlighting of keywords, errors, building projects, cleaning them, intgegration with VCS, etc. and usually provides default support for popular frameworks used for your language.

Java makes use of frameworks like Hibernate, Struts and Spring to extend the language and NetBeans or Intellij IDEA bring support for these tools to your Java project in a structured manor.

Answer (score 4):

**As per all answers I can come to a conclusion that Visual Studio is an IDE and .NET is a framework.
And also a framework(list of .dll) can be integrated into an IDE. Mean framework is a part of an IDE.**

Answer (score 1):

It was hard to find the difference because I was thinking about both as the similar thing. But what I now I understood is IDE is like chess game between two players playing at their own without any assistance. while, framework in the same scenario is like you are getting assistance from your computer(in case of framework are developers) and it gives you useful hints about moves and performs your task like if your queen is opened to attack it will make you only save the queen which in case of framework(You don't need to write code for specific things and you just use already written code in form of libraries and modules). in case of framework it will not give you hints but you have to explicitly learn it.